# Home Index issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
$ rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.1.4.1 application starting in development
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
*** SIGUSR2 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGUSR1 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGHUP not implemented, signal based logs reopening unavailable!
Puma starting in single mode...
* Puma version: 5.5.0 (ruby 3.0.2-p107) ("Zawgyi")
*  Min threads: 5
*  Max threads: 5
*  Environment: development
*          PID: 11220
* Listening on http://[::1]:3000
* Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-10-01 18:49:59 -0400
```

(0.7ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*)
Processing by Rails::WelcomeController#index as HTML
Rendering C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/te
mplates/rails/welcome/index.html.erb
Rendered C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/tem
plates/rails/welcome/index.html.erb (Duration: 34.4ms | Allocations: 493)
Completed 200 OK in 113ms (Views: 38.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations:
36
60)

```
Started GET "/home/index" for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-10-01 18:50:12 -0400

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/home/index"):
```

**I am extremely new at this - was wondering why I can't access home index page on local host 3000?**

Comment: Run `rake routes` in your terminal. Is there a route at `/home/index`? Your controller name is `welcome` so Rails will put the route there, Rails uses the controller name, it is just how it is set up to run so I suspect it has `welcome` instead of `home`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.